# How to design a database table that contains default, seed data as well as user-generated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, schema

I have a table with a set of statuses:

```
id: uuid
user_id: uuid
name: text
```

Each user starts out with the same set of default statuses, let's say `To Do`, `In-Progress`, `Complete`. Users have the ability to create their own statuses (and potentially change the name of the default statuses).

It seems like there's two options:

1. Create a set of shared defaults and leave `user_id` as `null`. The struggle with this approach is that if the user updates the name of a default status, I'll have to create a new status and update all the associations.
2. Create a set of defaults per user. The obvious downside is I'd create more data than necessary, but it makes the logic a lot simpler.

What's the best approach?

Comment: How is "best" calculated?

Answer (score 1):

In your migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :status, default: "To Do", null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The `t.timestamps` will generate an `id` column.

You set "defaults" in your User.rb model in app/models/user.rb:

```
  STATUSES = ["To Do", "Done"]
```

And in your users/form.html.erb you will have (example using `simple_form` gem):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :status, collection: User::STATUSES
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will let you to basically change the status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, should've added in the original question, but this model can also be referenced by other models, i.e. the default rows will have associations to other models.

Comment: Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html